# Function unionAll returns an empty table

Tags: union, union-all, dolphindb

I used function unionAll to combine two tables using the following script, but got an empty table. How come?

```
x=1 2 3;
y=4 5 6;
t1=table(x,y);
x=1 2 3;
y=5 6 7;
t2=table(x,y);
unionAll([t1,t2])
```

Answer (score 1):

Parameter partition of `unionAll` is an optional Boolean parameter with the default value of true. The result is a partitioned in-memory table with sequential domain. The partitioned table cannot be accessed by checking variables, you need to query the data through a select statement.

You can set parameter partition to false. It returns an unpartitioned in-memory table that can be accessed directly.

```
x=1 2 3;
y=4 5 6;
t1=table(x,y);
x=1 2 3;
y=5 6 7;
t2=table(x,y);
unionAll([t1,t2],false)
```

Output:

```
x   y
1   4
2   5
3   6
1   5
2   6
3   7
```